# R - using multiple functions in for-loop causes error - theyworkforyou Hansard API

Tags: r, function, for-loop, web-scraping

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to generate a `.csv` file containing all speeches from a UK MP in the house of commons for a given time frame using the `theyworkforyou.co.uk` API. I've written one function that collects the data:

```
getData <- function(url){
  require(jsonlite)
  raw.data <- readLines(url, warn="F")
  rd <- fromJSON(raw.data)
  rd <- as.data.frame(rd)
  return(rd)
}
```

whereby `url` would be defined as the given MP's theyworkforyou ID, as expressed in this list with 650 entries:

```
MP.ID <- as.list(MP.df$Person.ID) # All the MPs' ID's, e.g. 11111 for Ms. Smith
Scraper <- paste0("http://www.theyworkforyou.com/api/getHansard?key=SECRET=",MP.ID,"&year=2015&order=d&num=1000&output=js")
```

So, for example, this command

```
test.df <- getData(Scraper[1])
```

would return the text data (plus some auxiliary stuff) in a data frame.

Then, my next function cleans the text and leaves it with the relevant information and saves it out into a .csv containing the  respective MP's ID in the csv title, so as to uniquely identify it:

```
textClean <- function(scrapedData){
  Speaker.ID <- scrapedData$rows.person_id[1]
  slimScrape <- scrapedData[c(9,16,20)]
  slimScrape$Year <- substr(slimScrape$rows.hdate,1,4)
  slimScrape$Year <- as.numeric(slimScrape$Year)
  slimScrape <- subset(slimScrape,Year==2015)
  colnames(slimScrape) <- c("Date","Person.ID","Text.Full","Year")
  write.csv(slimScrape,file = paste0("HansardScrapes/","hansard",Speaker.ID,".csv"))
}
```

This also works when applied to a single case (i.e. the previously produced test.df), saving the right file to the desired location.

Now comes the problem. I want to loop this for all 650 MPs. It wont work. It returns the following error message:

> "Error: attempt to apply non-function"

when I try to run this loop:

```
for(i in 1:650(Scraper)){
  Contributions <- getData(Scraper[i])
  textClean(Contributions)
}
```

Again, I'm sorry if this is a really noobish question and the answer is completely obvious. I've tried working with lapply and sapply, but I can't quite wrap my head round what they do. Also, it didn't work either :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (loop over MP.ID)

```
lapply(MP.ID, function(mpid){
url <- paste0("http://www.theyworkforyou.com/api/getHansard?key=SECRET=",mpid,"&year=2015&order=d&num=1000&output=js")
scrapedData <- getData(url) 
textClean (scrapedData)
})
```

Comment: Hi there, this also worked. Thank you very very much, I can't believe that this problem that's taken 8 hours out of my life could be solved so simply - and in different ways. Do you think this solution is generally superior to looping?

Comment: No problem. Please read [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#lapply) section from hadley book

Answer (score 0):

The looping is written wrong, try:

```
for(i in 1:650){
  Contributions <- getData(Scraper[i])
  textClean(Contributions)
}
```

The 650(Scraper) you used is attempting to call a function called 650 (which doesn't and can't exist) on Scraper. You could try:

```
 for(i in 1:length(Scraper)){...
```

for more generality too.

Also, you should move your command `require(jsonlite)` out of the function - otherwise it will call it every time, when you only need to call it once a session.

If this doesn't fix your problem, paste a `dput(test.df)`, as otherwise to test it we'd have to sign up for an API key.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! Thanks also for taking the time and explaining why I got it wrong and how I could improve it. I am very grateful for your time!